# jQuery autocomplete, fill multiple fields by selecting suggested option

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have autocomplete jQuery script working for pulling suggestions from MySQL database when typing in form fields on the page (3 input fields).
That is working fine, but what I would like is to when I select suggested option in the first field - all 3 fields should be filled.
Fields that I have right now is first name, last name, and company. When I select the first name - last name and company should be automatically filled with data.

Here's php:

```
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">       
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() 
{
 $( "#first_name" ).autocomplete({
  source: 'autocomplete.php'
 });
});
$(function() 
{
 $( "#last_name" ).autocomplete({
  source: 'autocomplete.php'
 });
});
$(function() 
{
 $( "#company" ).autocomplete({
  source: 'autocomplete.php'
 });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

<div class="ui-widget">
 <p>First name</p>
 <input type="text" id="first_name">
</div>

<div class="ui-widget">
 <p>Last name</p>
 <input type="text" id="last_name">
</div>

<div class="ui-widget">
 <p>Company</p>
 <input type="text" id="company">
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the autocomplete.php file:

```
<?php

$host="localhost";
$username="user";
$password="password";
$databasename="dbname";

$connect=mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
$db=mysql_select_db($databasename);

$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];

$select =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jemployee WHERE first_name LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%'");
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($select)) 
{
$spojeno = $row['first_name'] . ' ' . $row['last_name'] . ' ' . $row['kompanija'];
$data[] = $spojeno;
}
//return json data
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

So, when the suggested option from "first_name" is selected - "last_name" and "company" should be filled with corresponding data from a database. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use something Jquery likes:

`$(document).on('keyup', '#firstname', funtion(){
     $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"ajax.php",
        data:$("#firstname").val();
      },
      success:function (res){
      $("#lastname").val(res.lastname);
      $("#company").val(res.company);
      },
     )};
});`

And PHP ajax.php file:

`<?php`

`\\Select lastname, company with $_POST['data']`

`echo json_endcode($result);`

Should check and handle the ajax response. If you can you this solution, please make it better.

Comment: Thanks. Not really sure what should be placed in Ajax though, not really familiar with Ajax and Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is passing the ajax "item" result as the autocomplete "value" :

It looks like this :

```
success: function (data) {
  response($.map(data, function (item) {
    return {
      label: item.Id, //the data that will be shown in the list !
      value: item //item holds "Id" and "Name" properties
    };
  }))
}
```

I then subscribe the **autoComplete** "select" event to prevent it's default behaviour.
I then fill the different fields I need to :

```
select: function(event, ui){
  //Update Customer Name Field on Id selection
  event.preventDefault()
  $("#CustomerId").val(ui.item.value.Id);
  $("#CustomerName").val(ui.item.value.Name);
},
```

here's the entire autocomplete call, in case it helps ;)

```
$("#CustomerId").autocomplete({
  source: function (request, response) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/.../../GetAvailablePartnerInformations",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: { prefix: request.term },
      success: function (data) {
        response($.map(data, function (item) {
          return {
            label: item.Id,
            value: item
          };
        }))
      }
    })
  },
  change: function (event, ui) {
    //Forces input to source values, otherwise, clears
    //NOTE : user could still submit right after typing => check server side
    if (!ui.item) {
      //http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-change -
      // The item selected from the menu, if any. Otherwise the property is null
      //so clear the item for force selection
      $(event.target).val("");
      $(event.target).addClass("is-invalid");
    }
    else {
      $(event.target).removeClass("is-invalid");
    }
  },
  select: function(event, ui){
    //Update Customer Name Field on Id selection
    event.preventDefault()
    //Note : the "value" object is created dynamically in the autocomplete' source Ajax' success function (see above)
    debugger;
    $("#CustomerId").val(ui.item.value.Id);
    $("#CustomerName").val(ui.item.value.Name);
  },
  messages: {
    noResults: "",
    results: function (resultsCount) { }
  },
  autoFocus: true,
  minLength: 0
})
```